# Get only first 2 chars from string

Tags: c, string

I would like to make a string out of the first two chars of a different string

So I have:

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string s = argv[1];
    string key = // here is where I dont know how to get the first 2 chars.
    printf("%s\n", key);
}
```

If `argv[1]` is: 1220kjs, I need string "key" to be 12, argv[1] can be numbers or characters. So if argv[1] is entered as jths528as, I need string "key" to be "jt".

I have tried various methods but can not get it to compile. s.Substring(0,2) gives me error: member reference base type 'string' aka 'char *') is not a structure or union

I found a solution:

```
string t = argv[1];
char key[3];
strncpy(key, t, 2);
key[2] = '\0';
```

Comment: `argv` is a two diamentional array, then how it is possible to take value `argv[1] is: 122085`

Comment: @un-lucky It looks like argv is supposed to be an array of strings.

Comment: Until we know what type argv is, it's hard to give you a good answer

Comment: Your question is unclear.  What does string `b` have to do with the issue?  As others have said, you need to tell us what type `argv` is.

Comment: If argv is a string[], then string a = argv[1]; string c = a.Substring(0, 2) would work provided that there is at least two elements in argv.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method that I used:

```
string key = argv[1];

char c[3] = {key[0], key[1], '\0'};

string s = c;

printf("string: %s\n", s);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given what you've provided in the question and from interpreting your meaning I can only assume that argv is a two dimensional array of either int or char.

```
string a = argv[1][0]; // so this has 1
string b = argv[1][1]; // this has 2 in it
```

You want c to be 12.

```
    int[,] t = new int[2, 6] {{1,2,3,4,5,6},
                              {1,2,2,0,8,5}};

    string a = Convert.ToString(t[1,0]);
    string b = Convert.ToString(t[1,1]);

    string c = a+b; // "12"
```

from here you can convert it to a number if you need it as 12.

Answer (score 0):

As the source string might be small like `"x"` or, in theory `""`, simply print with a size limitation:

```
if (argc >= 2) {
  int n = 2;
  char key[n + 1];
  // Print up to n characters & form a string.
  snprintf(key, n + 1, "%s", argv[1]); 
  printf("<%s>\n", key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Which compilator are you using?
I tried your code with gnu and works fine with substr.
The code below works too, you can try changing the costructor for example.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    string s(argv[1]);
    string key = s.substr(0,2);
    printf("%s\n", key.c_str());
}
```